# Why does English employ double possessive pronouns such as theirs and ours?

Tags: possessives, double-possessive

I am a native speaker of AmE.  I understand when and where to use *their vs theirs*, etc. etc.  (**i.e. Don't migrate this to ELL!**).  I've searched the site and google, and I have not quite seen an answer to my question.

Etymonline describes the word [*theirs*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/theirs#etymonline_v_49497) as:

> possessive pronoun, "their own," early 14c., from their + possessive -s, on analogy of his, etc. In form, a double possessive.

And, [their](https://www.etymonline.com/word/their):

> plural possessive pronoun, c. 1200, from Old Norse *þierra* [sic] "of them," genitive of plural personal and demonstrative pronoun *þeir* "they" (see they). Replaced Old English *hiera*. As an adjective from late 14c. **Use with singular objects, scorned by grammarians, is attested from c. 1300, and OED quotes this in Fielding, Goldsmith, Sydney Smith, and Thackeray.** Theirs (c. 1300) is a double possessive. Alternative form theirn (1836) is attested in Midlands and southern dialect in U.K. and the Ozarks region of the U.S.  **Emphasis mine**

(Parenthetical question, what do they mean by use with singular objects in this case?)

The entries for *our* and *ours* are similar.

Why does English have a double possessive pronoun?  And why does modifying it thusly change its usage?  Singular-plural possessive pronoun - possessive adjective; double-plural possessive pronoun - possessive pronoun?

[Theirs is used when there is not a following noun](https://www.askdifference.com/theirs-vs-their/), but, I don't understand why a double possessive would be used in this way.

> The book is theirs.
>
> That is their book.

We cannot say:

> The book is their.

nor

> That is theirs book.

But, for the life of me, I cannot figure out why making it a double possessive would make this happen!

Comment: I think that "possessive **s**" may also account for the difference between ***he / him*** and ***his***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It does for sure.  But, that is a singular possessive, no?  It belongs *to him*.  *It is his book*.  *The book is his.* etc.

Comment: Related - my own earlier question: [“Your and my (something)” vs “Yours and my…”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22289/difference-between-yours-and-your) Apparently the *orthographically explicitly possessive* form ***your's*** was far from unknown a couple of centuries ago.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed.  But, it doesn't quite explain why a single possessive pronoun becomes an adjective and a double becomes a pronoun . . .

Comment: Nothing does. Pieces of grammar like pronouns get misshapen in the gears as they go around, billions of times a day, year after year. You can't "explain" why one pronoun takes one form and a different one takes another, any more than you can "explain" why two fish have different sizes. Variation is the norm in evolution; it's consistency that's suspicious.

Comment: @JohnLawler This may be as close to an answer as any other.  But, is there a historical basis or anything else for this shift?  It would even be more satisfying if someone said this came from Old Norse or the like.

Comment: What makes you think it's a shift? New forms occur, they don't have to be conversions. There isn't always a used word with the right characteristics available.

Comment: @JohnLawler Perhaps I'm just seeking order in the universe.

Comment: Another "related" question posted by me: [Why is it usually “friend of his”, but no possessive apostrophe with “friend of Peter”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50588/why-is-it-usually-friend-of-his-but-no-possessive-apostrophe-with-friend-of) (Personally, I'm okay with both *friend of **him*** and *friend of **his***.)

Comment: Because pronouns don't behave like nouns?

Comment: @JohnLawler I guess it comes down to a larger question.  Why do we claim that language follows logical rules, then anytime it doesn't, we claim it doesn't?  I guess we should all just run away screaming ....

Comment: Incidentally, _theirs_ and _ours_ aren't "double possessive pronouns". They're possessive pronouns, period. _Our_ and _their_ are the adjective form, but they take _-s_ as pronouns. This is true for all personal pronouns except _my_ and _thy_, which take _-n_ from the old pre-vocalic variants _mine_ and _thine_ (like the eyes you should drink to me only with). The _-s_ isn't possessive any more than the _-n_ is. It's just a different paradigm.

Comment: As for following rules, it's the same as anything else. It doesn't follow simple rules, but when you look close enough you see patterns. But language rules are complicated by the fact that our culture doesn't look at language clearly. We think it's all letters and words, so sounds and constituents don't get noticed; but language rules work only for sounds and constituents, so it's kind of like trying to paint without noticing color.

Comment: @JohnLawler Clearly you've seen me paint.

Comment: @@JohnLawler: Dialectally, we also have/had ***yourn*** for ***your / yours***, which I always assumed was a reduced form of ***your one***. Is that true, and does the same "etymology" also apply to ***me / my / mine**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers OED: Alteration of your pron., after mine pron., thine pron. Compare hern n., his'n pron., ourn pron., theirn pron., and compare also yours pron.
Eng.Dial.Dict. comments on the regional distribution: ‘In gen. dialect use in the midl. and s. counties and Amer.’; Surv.Eng.Dial. records the word from the majority of midland and southern counties, with the exception of Cheshire and Nottinghamshire to the north, Norfolk and Suffolk to the east, and Devon and Cornwall to the west. Dict.Amer.RegionalEng. records the word chiefly from New England and southern and south Midland states.

Comment: @tchrist: Ah right! I'd forgotten about "Dickensian rustics" with their ***her'n / his'n***. But does OP's cited *Use with singular objects, scorned by grammarians* imply those dialectal ***'n*** forms were particularly / originally associated with only / primarily with *singular* referents *(This is **her'n / his'n**, These are **hers / his**)*?

Comment: That should be **þeirra** (ei, not ie).

Comment: @TimR Copied directly from source. Error is theirs, not mine. I could [sic] it, but it doesn't seem worth the effort.  I'll just leave a standing apology for any native speakers of Old Norse.

Comment: @DavidM  Yeah, I saw the typo was at Etymonline.  Just in case anyone was wondering about the vowel, I've [sic]'d it.

Comment: You mention *theirs* and *ours*.  Why not also  *hers*  ?

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, that too

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know why etymonline calls *theirs* 'a double possessive', but it's not.

The unfortunate terminology of 'the double possessive', aka 'the double genitive', is not due to the pronoun *theirs* itself but to the common construction like *a friend of theirs* where traditional grammar treats the preposition *of* as another possessive on top of the possessive pronoun *theirs*.

So in a construction that doesn't contain *of*, *theirs* itself is no double possessive:

> The book is theirs.

This example of yours, for example, doesn't contain *of*, so there's only one possessive, the possessive pronoun *theirs*, which means *their book*. (Note the subject of the first clause does contain *of*, so you can call it a double possessive.)

Now, some grammarians don't like the term 'the double possessive/genitive' even for constructions like *a friend of theirs*.

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Page 468), for example, treats *She's a friend of Kim's* not as a double possessive/genitive but as a oblique genitive:

> ...we do not regard *of* as a genitive case marker, and hence there is only one genitive here, not two.

As for the distinction between *their* and *theirs*, CGEL classifies the former as a **dependent** genitive (possessive) and the latter as an **independent** genitive (possessive), which easily explains why these don't work:

> **The book is their.*
>
> **That is theirs book.*

Comment: Thanks, that's actually quite helpful!

Comment: Etymonline's wording is correct, and explains what it means: "**In form**, a double possessive". It just means that the form "theirs" was created by combining the possessive word *their* and the possessive suffix *-s.* Likewise, "children" can be described as a "double plural" *in form* (but obviously not as a "double plural" in any syntactic sense) because it was created by adding the plural suffix *-en* to the plural form *childer.* The CGEL's terms "dependent" and "independent" are of course appropriate for the purposes of synchronic description of the grammar of English.

Comment: @sumelic Forgive me about my total ignorance about "early 14c. English" discussed there, but did it use "-s" without an apostrophe as the possessive suffix back then?

Comment: I don't know the history very well, but the use of the apostrophe in the genitive is complicated and has not consistently followed the same usage as modern English. Related questions: [When did it become incorrect to use apostrophes with possessive pronouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117543/when-did-it-become-incorrect-to-use-apostrophes-with-possessive-pronouns), [Origins of possessive pronouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9467), [Why is an apostrophe used in the genitive “-’s”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96898)

Comment: @sumelic Aside from the issue of whether an apostrophe is required as part of the possessive marker, I don't quite understand where this notion of viewing the '-s' in _theirs_ as the possessive marker came from. If the '-s' were really the possessive marker, why wouldn't _mine_ end in '-s'? Moreover, it's clear from my own answer that _theirs_ isn't a double possessive. So why would anyone think of the '-s' as the possessive marker in _theirs_?

Comment: *Mines* exists (the OED describes it as "regional (chiefly Scottish)"), but did not become standard, possibly because the forms *my* and *mine* were already differentiated without the presence of a final /z/. As tchrist mentioned, *hern, yourn, ourn, theirn, hisn* also used to exist, or exist dialectally, as alternatives to the independent genitive forms ending in *-s.* It isn't necessary for modern English speakers to view the *-s* in *theirs* as the same morpheme found in the suffix *-'s*;  the only thing I'm saying is that they are etymologically the same in origin.

Comment: What other explanation is there for the origin of the forms *hers, theirs, yours* and *ours*? The final s in these words is not inherited from Old English. Regarding why we would only see the possessive suffix added to the independent forms, I'd guess that could be explained by one of or a combination of the following factors: dependent forms are in a weaker phonological position, and so tend to be shorter; and dependent forms have a a fixed position relative to the possessed noun phrase, which makes their meaning fairly clear even without the addition of an ending.

Comment: I wonder if this is a generalization of a transformation needed for "her", which can be an objective pronoun as well (as in "I went with her"). We use the -s suffix to distinguish "X is her" (meaning X is the same as her) from "X is hers" (meaning X belongs to her). But we don't need that for the masculine form, which has objective "him" versus possessive "his".