# "Your or someone else's" or "Yours or someone else's"?

Tags: possessives, expression-choice, possessive-pronouns

Should I say

> Your or someone else's

Or

> Yours or someone else's

When I am referring to an item that may either belong to the person I am addressing, or someone else?

Example context:

> Check your/s or someone else's current balance.

Comment: Could you give a couple of sentences to give some context? In the meantime, you might want to look at possessive adjectives and possessive pronouns.

Comment: @Greybeard I have had a look at [the question on yours vs your](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22289/difference-between-yours-and-your) but still unsure. I will add examples now.

Comment: 'You or mine'???